# If User Authentication Cannot Work Propoerly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I want to make a authentication with **if user** method. When I do console.log(user) and cosole.log(kullanici) I get the right data.

**kullanici** means the user that shown in profile.

**user** means the user which is currently logged in(req.user)

**My app.js file:**

```
app.get('/kullanici/:id', function(req, res){
  Kullanici.findById(req.user
    ).exec(function(err, user){
    Kullanici.findById(req.params.id, function(err, kullanici){
      res.render("kullanici",{
      kullanici:kullanici,
      user:user,
    });
  });
 });
```

});

**My kullanici.pug file:**

```
if user
  if user._id == kullanici._id
    a.button.btn.btn-light(href='/kullanici/duzenleme/' + kullanici.id, style="margin-right:85%;")Düzenle
```

But I couldnt understand why it is not working. Can someone help me to solve this:

Comment: Try console logging both the value and type of both `user._id` and `kullanici._id`.  If they are strings, also make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces.  You might also log the result of the test `console.log(user._id == kullanici._id)`

Comment: no it gives the ID of profile user and req.user's ID

Comment: So that it is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this to my pug template===>

```
if user
  if user._id == ""+kullanici._id+""
    a.button.btn.btn-light(href='/kullanici/duzenleme/' + kullanici.id, style="margin-right:85%;")Düzenle
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default `if` expression in pug, try using JavaScript to evaluate the truth of the expression. So, instead of `if user._id == kullanici._id` , try using `- if(user._id == kullanici._id)`

Comment: It doesnt work. I dont know why. I dont get error either.(I am not sure if I used either correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a space between a Pug tag declaration and its content.

```
a(href='#')Content //incorrect
a(href='#') Content //correct
```

In this case, you need to add a space after the closing parenthesis (before Düzenle) like this:

```
if user
  if user._id == kullanici._id
    a.button.btn.btn-light(href='/kullanici/duzenleme/' + kullanici.id, style="margin-right:85%;") Düzenle
```

Comment: It is not about that. In my real script there is a space. Button works fine.

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL Please ensure the code in your question matches your real code.